# How to count how many delimeters per row there are in Python

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv, count

I produce a query with 13 columns of values. Every single ones of these values are manually entered. That means there is roughly less than 10% chance that the rows entered are wrong. However that is not the issue. the issue is sometimes certain special characters are entered that can cause havoc to the database. I need to filter/remove this content from the CSV file

Here is a simple sample of the output of the CSV file

```
TypeOfEntry;Schoolid;Schoolyear;Grade;Classname;ClassId;firstname;lastname;Gender;nationality;Street;housenumber;Email;

;;;;;;;;;;;;; (1st line empty, 13 semicolons per row)

U;98645;2022;4;4AG;59845;John;Bizley;Male;United Kingdom;Canterburrystreet; 15a; Jb2004@hotmail.com;
U;98645;2022;4;4AG;59847;Alice;Schmidt;Female;United Kingdom;Milton street; 2/3; alice.schmidt@hotmail.com;
```

Now in rare occasions sometimes someone might want to add a second email which is not allowed but they still do it and whats worse they add a semicolon to it. Meaning that when the csv is loaded there are rows that surpass 13 columns.

`U;98645;2022;5;6CD;59845;Billy;Snow;Male;United Kingdom;Freedom street; 2a; BillyS@gmail.com;Billysnow2004@hotmail.com;`

Therefore to solve this problem I need to count the number of deliemters there are in each row, and if I do find a row that passed that count, I need to clear that excessve data even if it means losing that data for that particular person. So that means everything after the 13 column needs to be removed.

Here is my code sample in python. You will also notice that I am filtering other special characters from the csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv("schooldata.csv", sep = ';')
data.columns = ['TypeOfEntry','Schoolid','Schoolyear','Grade','Classname','ClassId','Firstname','Lastname','Gender','Nationality','Street','Housenumber','Email']
date = datetime. now(). strftime("%Y_%m_%d")

data = data.convert_dtypes()
#df = data.dataframe()

rep_chars = '°|^|!|"|\(|\)|\?'
rep_chars2 = r'\'|\`|\´|\*|#'

data = data.replace(rep_chars, '', regex=True)
data = data.replace(rep_chars2, '', regex=True)
data = data.replace('\+', '-', regex=True)

print(data.head())
print(data .dtypes)
data.to_csv(f'scoolexport_{date}.csv', sep= ';', date_format='%Y%m%d', index=False)
```

Comment: hmm, why dont you just create new data frame from the source df, - using only the first 13 columns?

Comment: I want to say "***Never trust user input!***", this should typically be escaped/corrected during data generation ;)

Comment: @NoobVB how can i set it that it only has 13 columns and no more?

Comment: load all data to initial data frame, lets say df, later just use `df.iloc[:, : 13]`, or even copy first 13 cols to the new df2, `df2 = df.iloc[:, : 13].copy()`

Comment: Though I like your solution @NoobVB, my problem is I need some form of loop or count function that would enable me to not only correct it but also notify me that the following user has an issue with their data.

Comment: Can't you fix this in the SQL query and strip of excess values after an unexpected `;` in the column content?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried stripping it off in postgres using regexp_replace(Email , '[^\w]+' ,'','gi') as "EZMail" However it didnt work naturally since the  @ sign is a special character and it only did it once, which was not at all what I wanted.

Comment: Why not just strip off anything after the  first `;`?  e.g. `substr(email, 1, strpos(email, ';')  - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

very very basic aproach, but maybe will be enough:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Test\test.csv", sep = ';')

data = df.iloc[:, : 13].copy() # data to use in later code

excessive_data = df.iloc[:, 13: ].copy().reset_index(drop=True) # excessive data will land after columns 13
if not excessive_data.empty:
    # checking if any excessive data is present 
    pos = excessive_data[excessive_data.notnull().all(axis=1)].index.tolist()
    print(f"excessive data is present in rows index:{pos}")
```

Comment: So i get the exception has occurrer error. Error tokenizing data. Expected 13 fields in line 12, saw 15

Comment: Perhaps a rethinking of the entire process. I assume you do not expect the user to enter a single string ( *U;98645;2022;4;4AG;59845; ...), but each component has a UI field of its own, and the final string constructed from the combination. So validate the each field as entered  or during combining the fields. If a semicolon or other invalid character is detected then generate the error message at that point.  Your issue never occurs then as it never gets out of the UI.  Goes along with  Mozway's dictum
**"Never trust user input!"**. And another **catch errors as soon as they can be caught**.